# Is it possible to have a true full-screen mode for Google Books?

Tags: google-books

When I press the "full-screen" button in Google Books, about a third of my vertical space is still taken up by various toolbars. This makes it extremely difficult to read efficiently. Is there any way to remove these toolbars in "full-screen" mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new "reader" Google eBook interface is quite minimal, and if you use <kbd>f11</kbd> you can make it extremely full screen. Here's [Google eBook Reader](http://books.google.com/books/reader?id=Y7sOAAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover&output=reader&pg=GBS.PA1) I get by clicking the reader button...

[image]

and here's the [old traditional Google Books UI](http://books.google.com/books?id=Y7sOAAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=twopage&q&f=true) I get when I click the book cover itself:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What seems to works for me (I am currently using Firefox, if that is of any relevance) is this:

- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> on your keyboard (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and scroll down with your mouse), so the entire page shrinks
- next, press the 'magnifying glass with a +' button on the menu on top of the page - this increases only the book, but not the surrounding text
- repeat this process until you are satisfied with the result :)

I admit this is not a very practical solution and it shrinks any other Google books sites you have open, but it is another way of fixing the problem.

I hope some of this works for you!

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox, go to *Tools* → *Web Developer* → *Inspect*. When you click on it, you will have the ability to select HTML objects and select "Delete Node" from a drop-down menu. You can use this to delete all parts of the page except the book.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff's answer is correct, but unfortunately it only applies to the so-called *eBooks* in Google's collection, as those are the only ones that have the red "READ NOW" button in the left panel.

However, I have found a simple workaround that seems to provide this same functionality to other books (if they offer preview privileges): place the parameter `&output=reader` in the address bar, immediately after the book ID. For example, you would edit this address:

[http://books.google.com/books?id=HCkBC0dcjHAC&printsec=frontcover](http://books.google.com/books?id=HCkBC0dcjHAC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r)

to this:

[http://books.google.com/books?id=HCkBC0dcjHAC&output=reader&printsec=frontcover](http://books.google.com/books?id=HCkBC0dcjHAC&output=reader&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r)

(By doing this, you will exchange the ability for *scrolling* through books for that of *page turning*, but the benefit is additional screen real-estate at the top of the page.)

Answer (score 1):

I also prefer kmote's solution when it works, but it only works for books that google has added on to google play. I have written a small Greasemonkey script to make the full-screen button on google reader behave the way it should.

- [Screenshot](http://shitikanth.wordpress.com/2012/06/30/google-books-fullscreen-preview/)
- [Download script from userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/137380)
- [Get Greasemonkey for firefox](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)
- [Get Greasemonkey (tampermonkey) for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo)

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy the Embed link from Google Books.

   `<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:0px" src="http://books.google.com/books?id=CFHw8jSEWwkC&lpg=PP1&pg=PP1&output=embed" width=500 height=500></iframe>`
2. Change the height and width parameters to 100%.

   `<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:0px" src="http://books.google.com/books?id=CFHw8jSEWwkC&lpg=PP1&pg=PP1&output=embed" width=100% height=100%></iframe>`
3. Paste into a blank text file and save as HTML on your local machine.

   `test.html`
4. Open the HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take each element and hide it or delete it by using F12. It works on Google Chrome.

[image]

Just right click the element you want to hide or delete and then select "`inspect`" (`inspeccionar` in spanish).
Then right click on the element in the tool console and select delete element or hide element.
**Make sure not to reload** otherwise you have to start again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using the Firefox browser.  Then I got the Google Play book app, and the full pages were displayed.  I am reading a book on an iPad so some of the answers above would require other keys, but the Google Play app does the job for me.